# How to install and use NACL ported library in our development environment

Tags: ffmpeg, google-nativeclient

i want to use ffmpeg nacl ported library in my project. i know we can install using using git. but in my develope environment git is not allowed. i have downloaded the zip file and unzipped it. and followed these steps:

1. download
2. unzip it:  tar -xvjpf ffmpeg-2.1.3.tar.bz2
3. go to Naclport folder: cd ffmpeg-2.1.3
4. /home/devesh/ffmpeg-2.1.3 $./configure
5. /home/devesh/ffmpeg-2.1.3 $make
6. install the library : sudo make install

now when i am trying to use this library header files my compiler not able to get it.

Is GIT is the only way to install nacl ports??

Comment: http://neumscs.wordpress.com/2014/07/24/how-to-compile-naclports-ffmpeg maybe help?